# Divide 2d Matrix into different rectangles C++

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming, array-algorithms

[image: for example]

I want to create c++ code that get all different rectangles within 2d matrix
i need to get all cases for example the left part of the picture i got all vertical rectangles and the right picture i got some vertical and some horizontal
i need to get all possible ways like picture
in other way i need to have output like that
array each element within it have array of objects every object have the start of the rectangle and the end of it say (0,0) to (0,3)

Comment: Ask yourself, how many `(x,y)` coordinates are there in a 2D Array? Now ask, how many pairs of such `(x,y)` form a rectangle? Here pair means `{ (x1,y1)  , (x2,y2) }`.

Comment: ok thank you man i will try to think like that

Comment: Apparently the number of partitions grows exponentially in the size, so any algorithm enumerating all of them wil have an exponential running time.